[@notifee/react-native]: foregroundServiceType 0x000000C0 is not a subset of foregroundServiceType attribute 0x00000800 in service element of manifest
In a video conferencing app, I recently added a foreground service to my App's manifest because after the app is in background for about a minute, others in a call are not able to see or hear the video & audio.
Using @notifee/react-native I declared
// for android foreground
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  notifee.registerForegroundService(notification => {
    return new Promise(() => {
      // handle background event
      notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({type, detail}) => {
        const {pressAction} = detail;

        if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && pressAction?.id === 'mic') {
          const result = togggleForegroundMic();

          if (result) {
            notifee.displayNotification({
              id: notification.id,
              body: notification.body,
              android: {
                ...notification.android,
                asForegroundService: true,
                foregroundServiceTypes: [
                  AndroidForegroundServiceType.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA,
                  AndroidForegroundServiceType.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE,
                ],
                actions: [
                  {
                    title: result,
                    pressAction: {id: 'mic'},
                  },
                  // {
                  //   title: 'Loud Speaker',
                  //   pressAction: {id: 'speaker'},
                  // },
                ],
              },
            });
          }
        }
      });

      notifee.onForegroundEvent(({type, detail}) => {
        if (
          type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS &&
          detail?.pressAction?.id === 'mic'
        ) {
          const result = togggleForegroundMic();

          if (result) {
            notifee.displayNotification({
              id: notification.id,
              body: notification.body,
              android: {
                ...notification.android,
                asForegroundService: true,
                foregroundServiceTypes: [
                  AndroidForegroundServiceType.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA,
                  AndroidForegroundServiceType.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE,
                ],
                actions: [
                  {
                    title: result,
                    pressAction: {id: 'mic'},
                  },
                  // {
                  //   title: 'Loud Speaker',
                  //   pressAction: {id: 'speaker'},
                  // },
                ],
              },
            });
          }
        }
        if (
          type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS &&
          detail?.pressAction?.id === 'speakder'
        ) {
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

in the "foregroundServiceTypes" I declared the microphone & camera services in the array
but this causes my app to crash with the following error

FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.collabnowmobilecleint, PID: 30221 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service app.notifee.core.ForegroundService@cd7fb43 with Intent { act=app.notifee.core.ForegroundService.START cmp=com.collabnowmobilecleint/app.notifee.core.ForegroundService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: foregroundServiceType 0x000000C0 is not a subset of foregroundServiceType attribute 0x00000800 in service element of manifest file at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4289) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:236) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2001) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7684) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: foregroundServiceType 0x000000C0 is not a subset of foregroundServiceType attribute 0x00000800 in service element of manifest file at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2075) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987) at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:6720) at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:742) at app.notifee.core.ForegroundService.onStartCommand(SourceFile:21) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4271) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:236) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2001) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7684) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980) Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundInnerLocked(ActiveServices.java:1396) at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundLocked(ActiveServices.java:1034) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setServiceForeground(ActivityManagerService.java:15727) at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:3056) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3153)

I tried adding the following permissions to my app's manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA" />

I also added the following as an attribute to the application tag
<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone">

I'm expecting the Microphone & Camera to still stay active when the App is in the background/minimized

Please share where you declared the foreground service type, both in the code when invoking the foreground service and also in the manifest, where the service needs to be registered.

Found the solution
Seems I didn't specify the foreground service type as described in the docs: https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/foreground-service#specifying-foreground-service-types
Adding the snippet below fixed the issue for me
<service 
        android:name="app.notifee.core.ForegroundService" 
        android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone"
        tools:replace="android:foregroundServiceType" />

